# Paste a range variable at the location of another variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

Im setting the location I want to paste at with column_find. I want to paste a range (user_data) at that cell. The macro runs but only pastes 1 value from the range. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Column_Locate()

    Dim current_month As Variant
    Dim column_find As Range
    Dim user_data As Range

    current_month = Worksheets("Inputs").Cells(4, 4).Value

    Set column_find = Worksheets("Feeder").Range("E2:CZ2").Find(current_month, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(8, -1)

    Debug.Print column_find.Address(0, 0)

    Set user_data = Worksheets("Unique Users Data").Range("B2:C3")

    Worksheets("Feeder").Select

    column_find = user_data

End Sub
```

Comment: In your last line of code ... column_find.value = user_data.value seems to work for me ... if you want values copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to adjust the size of "target" range (i.e. `column_find`) accordingly to the "source" one (i.e. `user_data`)

also avoid use of *Select*/*Selection*/*Activate*/*ActiveXXX* pattern , which is both time consuming and prone to have you quickly lose control over your ranges reference and adopt a fully qualified range reference pattern (for instance with the use of `With... End With` construct)

so you would code (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Column_Locate()
    Dim current_month As Variant
    Dim column_find As Range
    Dim user_data As Range

    current_month = Worksheets("Inputs").Cells(4, 4).Value

    Set user_data = Worksheets("Unique Users Data").Range("B2:C3")

    With Worksheets("Feeder") 'reference "Feeder" worksheet
        Set column_find = .Range("E2:CZ2").Find(current_month, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(8, -1) 'search referenced sheet range "E2:CZ2" for 'current_month' value

        If Not column_find Is Nothing Then 'if the searched value has been found
            With user_data 'reference "source" range
                Debug.Print column_find.Address(0, 0)
                column_find.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = user_data.Value ' reference a "target" range as the one with found value but with same size as "source" range and write values
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting. Great stuff. All these commands in VBA I have no idea exist. One follow-up..... What if I wanted my source (user_data) to be transposed at the target?